# Is this scene from Kiki's delivery service reference to Superman?

Tags: superman, reference, studio-ghibli, kikis-delivery-service

At the end of the movie Kiki's delivery service there is a scene where reporter shouts: "Is it a bird? No, no it is a girl. A witch!" 
At least it is this way in English subtitles on Netflix.

That greatly reminded me this scene from Superman:

But it seems like a very unlikely reference in japanese animated movie.
Is it just a coincidence then?

Comment: The first question to answer is: Is this in the Japanese version or just the dub of Kiki?

Comment: @laurel hmm, not sure, I saw original with english subtitles only.

Comment: I vaguely remember this line from the dub but if it’s also in the subtitles for the original Japanese then it’s pretty likely to be a faithful translation. (It wasn’t clear which version you saw from the question)

Comment: You think they never heard of Superman in Japan?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It is not the same to hear about something and to use reference to it in movie, is it?

Comment: @TGar: it's not! Let me rephrase: you think they don't have enough cultural awareness of Superman in Japan for the "Is it a bird?" reference to have meaning?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Now it seems to me that maybe I don't have such cultural awereness. Because I did not considered this scene to be that famous generally until now. But I believe you if you say it is.